# VBScript : How to identify the hidden excel tabs in excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript

How to identify the hidden excel tabs in excel Workbook using vbscript, but not VBA. How to get the properties of  each tab like name, color, visibility using VBScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `objExcel` is your Excel application object:

```
For i = 1 To objExcel.Sheets.Count

    ' Display the name of hidden worksheets...
    If Not objExcel.Sheets(i).Visible Then
        WScript.Echo objExcel.Sheets(i).Name & " is not visible."
    End If

    ' Get the tab color value of each worksheet...
    WScript.Echo "Tab color value = " & objExcel.Sheets(i).Tab.Color

Next
```

Comment: Thanks Bond, it worked. I have one more query. Using vbscript, how to find/search a word in an excel only from the visible cells. i.e if a word is present in any of the hidden rows or columns, it should not return that. Currently, i am using as below, but it returns the text irrespective of visibility. How to retrict visiblity for this? Set foundText = excelFile.worksheets(i).Range("A1:H500").Find("Hello")

Comment: Please submit a new topic for your question. It will help other experts to see it and also help those with similar questions find it in the future.